# Как перенаправить команду от родительского контрола к дочернему?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

Допустим есть вот такой `UserControl`:

```
<UserControl>
       <Button Name="button"></Button>
</UserControl>
```

В его `code-behind` обьявлено свойство зависимости:

```
 public partial class Test : UserControl
{
    public LoginButton()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public ICommand Command
    {
        get { return (ICommand)GetValue(CommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CommandProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Command", typeof(ICommand), typeof(Test));
}
```

Как сделать чтобы привязываясь к команде из `UserControl`, привязка произошла  к кнопке `button`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблему решил.

1) Нужно дать имя `UserControl`. Допустим `x:Name = this`.

2) Привязать кнопку к родительскому контролу и его команде.

```
<Button   Command="{Binding Command, ElementName=this}"/>
```